# Как не прервывать скрипт из за ошибки imagic открытия файла?

Tags: php, imagick

обрабатываю файлы imagic и при битом файле скрипт останавливается, как этого избежать и просто сделать при возникновении ошибки continue; в цикле?

Пробовал несколько вариантов как открытия файлы с места

```
unlink('temp.png');
file_put_contents('temp.png',$sFile);
$print = new Imagick('temp.png');
```

Пишет при битом файле

```
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Failed to read the file'
```

И останавливает скрипт.

Так же пробовал без промежуточного сохранения

```
  curl_close($curl);
  $print = new Imagick( );
  $print->readImageBlob($sFile);
```

Пишет `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Unable to read image blob'` и тоже останавливает скрипт...

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Про исключения слышали? И их обработку?

Comment: Спасибо, честно говоря раньше не приходилось сталкиваться, все получилось,      try
     {
         $print->readImageBlob($sFile);
     } catch (Exception $e) {
continue;
     }